# Multiple key values.

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a function that reads contents from a file and appends them in a dictionary. The contents of the file are author name, book name, quantity, and price, which are all separated by commas in the file.The author is the key for all the values. My code is:

```
for line in infile:
    lineList = line.strip("\n").split(",")
    author = lineList[0] + "," + lineList[1]
    book = [lineList[2], lineList[3], lineList[4]]

    theInventory[author] = [book]
```

It doesn't let me add extra books to the author. So William Shakespeare has Romeo and Juliet, and Macbeth. It will take in Romeo and Juliet, but then override this with Macbeth as the new value for the key. I want both books to be values for Shakespeare,William. These are the contents of the file:

Shakespeare,William,Romeo And Juliet,5,5.99
Shakespeare,William,Macbeth,3,7.99
Dickens,Charles,Hard Times,7,27.00

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create dictionary from 2-D list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449030/create-dictionary-from-2-d-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that you were over-writing the author's entry in the inventory every time. Thus, the last book of each author is what would have shown up. This should fix that error:

```
theInventory = {}
for line in infile:
    lineList = line.strip("\n").split(",")
    author = lineList[0] + "," + lineList[1]
    book = [lineList[2], lineList[3], lineList[4]]
    if author not in theInventory:
        theInventory[author] = []
    theInventory[author].append(book)
```

Of course, there is a more object-oriented way of doing this, too:

```
from collections import defaultdict
class Book:
    def __init__(name, price):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Book):
            return False
        return self.name == other.name

inventory = defaultdict(dict)
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    for lname, fname, title, quantity, price in csv.reader(infile):
        price = float(price)
        quantity = int(quantity)
        author = "%s,%s" %(lname, fname)
        inventory[author][Book(title, price)] = quantity
```

Comment: Yep, having a list as the value is the way to go. `collections.defaultdict` would be useful here, too.

Comment: I did it similar to how you did this, but my professor wants it in a particular fashion, which is why I had to create it the way I did. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are using [author] as the unique ID for each field.  When you have 2 books with the same author, the earlier items get overridden.

I don't suggest using author as a way to get multiple books for that author.  It is poor practice to tie data together in such a way.

I would create a list of book objects, and each book object has the attributes you've described.  Then I would query the list of books for all books with authors containing "Shakespeare".

This also allows you to query your data in ways besides only author.